# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error from Python pip in Ubuntu 16.0.4

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, pip

Python pip suddenly stopped working and it gives ***SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED*** error.
I am not able to install any of the pip packages. 
**sudo pip install scikit-image** is throwing following error

> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)'),)': /simple/scikit-image/ 
>     Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-image/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: 
>  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/scikit-image/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)'),)) - skipping

I tried using `easy_install` but it is giving the same SSL error.
When I tried downloading a zip file of 5GB using wget , the downloaded file size is in KBs
Can someone please suggest the solution for above problem.

Thank You

Comment: Does this started to happen with the upgrade to 9.0.2? Whats the output of `pip --version` ?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue after having updated to v10.0.0, anyone able to solve?

Answer (score 7):

It can be related to the [recent change](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5288#issuecomment-383071739) of PyPI domains.
Public announcements of the change:
https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2018/03/warehouse-all-new-pypi-is-now-in-beta.html
https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2017/01/time-to-upgrade-your-python-tls-v12.html

If you run pip from behind proxy/firewall, please ensure it allows access to/from:

- *pypi.org*
- *files.pythonhosted.org*

Also you may give a try to certain `pip` options:
`$ python -m pip <command> --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org ... --proxy ...`

In case there is a problem with outdated OS root certificates, pip uses urllib3 and certifi libraries for [SSL certificate verification](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#ssl) and TLS connection. You could give it a try:
`$ pip install --user --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org certifi`

If still no-go, browse to PyPI.org and download the [python certifi package](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/) from its **"Download Files"** section, and install manually:
`$ pip install --user --no-index ~/Downloads/certifi-2018.11.29-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

By the way, unlike with `sudo apt`, running `sudo pip install` command with root access to install or upgrade Python packages is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49989474), because it interferes with your OS package manager subsystem (apt,yum,etc) and may affect essential OS (Ubuntu,Debian,Fedora,etc) components that depend upon your system python. 
The `--user` flag allows to install packages to your home dir (under ~/.local/lib); else you could use [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv).

And for the system-wide package deployments, Ubuntu expects us to use `apt` package manager. There are many (not all) python packages, including `scikit` that you needed – just use `$ apt search` (same as older `$ apt-cache search`) to find it, `$ apt show` for package description, and `$ sudo apt install` to install.