# Python (pip) - RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.9.1) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, urllib3, chardet

I found several pages about this issue but none of them solved my problem.

Even if I do a :

```
pip show
```

I get :

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.9.1) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 480, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2322, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2328, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    from urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: cannot import name DependencyWarning
```

What I did :

```
pip install --upgrade chardet
```

but as explain up, it gaves me the same error.

so I did :

```
sudo apt remove python-chardet
```

and unistalling all his dependecies.
After I reinstall it -> the same :'(

I did the same for `python-pip`. After reinstalling it -> the same. 
Here are the lines about `urllib3` and `chardet` versions needed :
extract of `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py` :

```
    # Check urllib3 for compatibility.
    major, minor, patch = urllib3_version  # noqa: F811
    major, minor, patch = int(major), int(minor), int(patch)
    # urllib3 >= 1.21.1, <= 1.22
    assert major == 1
    assert minor >= 21
    assert minor <= 22

    # Check chardet for compatibility.
    major, minor, patch = chardet_version.split('.')[:3]
    major, minor, patch = int(major), int(minor), int(patch)
    # chardet >= 3.0.2, < 3.1.0
    assert major == 3
    assert minor < 1
    assert patch >= 2


# Check imported dependencies for compatibility.
try:
    check_compatibility(urllib3.__version__, chardet.__version__)
except (AssertionError, ValueError):
    warnings.warn("urllib3 ({0}) or chardet ({1}) doesn't match a supported "
                  "version!".format(urllib3.__version__, chardet.__version__),
                  RequestsDependencyWarning)
```

My versions are :

```
ii  python-urllib3 1.9.1-3   all HTTP library with thread-safe connection pooling for Python 
ii  python-chardet  2.3.0-1  all universal character encoding detector for Python2
```

I don't have no more ideas...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You do have a mixed setup (both `apt` and `pip` were used to install system-wide, which is common), and it indeed doesn't match the supported versions of modules required by requests (and pip v1.5.6 is also quite old).

The `requests` (which version? likely leftover from `pip install`) requires:
urllib3: 1.21.1 - 1.22
chardet: 3.0.2 - 3.1.0

You have:
urllib3 (1.9.1) from python-urllib3 1.9.1-3 debian package
chardet (2.3.0) from python-chardet 2.3.0-1 debian package

Two options:

- either downgrade `requests` to the version from your OS distribution (see what's available with `apt show python-requests`), or older versions at pypi.org, or
- or install newer urllib3 and chardet (you can download the wheel files manually from pipy.org and do `pip install` on them, including any dependencies), either at user level (`--user` pip install option) or in a virtualenv.

You can test everything in a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv) (`apt show python-virtualenv`). It should even deploy a newer pip for you inside of its virtual envs. It is also [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version) to install a newer pip 10.0.1 at the user-level (`--user`) alongside your OS-vendored pip but you need to be [careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881448/importerror-cannot-import-name-main-after-upgrading-tp-pip-10-0-0-for-python-ve) about that. Good luck!

Answer (score 148):

This is because of different requests module installed by the OS and the python dependencies for your local installation.

It can be solved by upgrading requests:

```
pip install requests
```

or

```
pip3 install requests
```

Comment: this also worked   `sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade requests`

Comment: `pip3 install requests -U` also works.

Answer (score 34):

The best practice would be to make sure requests **and its dependencies** are up to date.

*Python 2*

> $ pip install --upgrade requests

*Python 3*

> $ pip3 install --upgrade requests

Answer (score 32):

Faced similar error when upgraded to `urllib3 1.23`. Installation of older version `1.22` resolved this error for me.

Did following to install the older `urllib3` version:

1. `pip uninstall urllib3`
2. `pip install urllib3==1.22`

Comment: For selenium, make sure to use 1.26 (pip install urllib3==1.26)

Answer (score 19):

I encountered this issue when trying to run `docker-compose <some-action>` after a system update.

There are a few reasons that can lead to the error mentioned.

I'll add another solution here, maybe it will help somebody if the other solutions doesn't fit his specific scenario.

The following combination solved the problem for me:

```
pip uninstall urllib3    
pip uninstall chardet
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 13):

For me the fix was:

```
pip uninstall urllib3    
pip uninstall chardet
pip install requests
```

Stack:

Centos 7.6.1810

docker-compose 1.24.1 build 4667896 (docker-compose logs give me the warn)

python 2.7.5

pip 8.1.2

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me. Simply execute below commands.

```
$ sudo pip uninstall requests

$ sudo pip install requests

$ sudo pip uninstall docopt

$ sudo pip install docopt
```

Here's the reference [link for detail](https://medium.com/@gloriapalmagonzalez/urllib3-1-22-or-chardet-2-2-1-doesnt-match-a-supported-version-requestsdependencywarning-97c36e0cb561)!

Answer (score 6):

Simple you have to update only -

```
 pip3 install requests
```

Answer (score 5):

All that's needed is `sudo pip install --upgrade requests`.

Without sudo you'll get `Permission denied`,
and if you add `--user` it won't install into system python.

After this, `pip list` does not get a RequestsDependencyWarning.

The output on my system:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade requests

/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.2) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Collecting requests
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 510kB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (1.25.2)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/75/f692a584e85b7eaba0e03827b3d51f45f571c2e793dd731e598828d380aa/certifi-2019.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (158kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 1.1MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Installing collected packages: certifi, requests
  Found existing installation: requests 2.21.0
    Uninstalling requests-2.21.0:
      Successfully uninstalled requests-2.21.0
Successfully installed certifi-2019.3.9 requests-2.22.0
```

[I would have simply added a small comment on @h3xStream's answer,
but don't have enough reputation.]

Answer (score 5):

In my case there was a problem with the chardet package. I had installed two versions (2.3.0 and 3.04) and for some reason python loaded the old one. My solution was to delete the package manually:

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chardet*
```

and install it again

```
pip install chardet
```

If not already done update also urllib3 and requests to the latest version

```
pip install --upgrade urllib3
pip install --upgrade requests
```

Answer (score 4):

At any moment, check the source is the way, specially when the developer has left clear instruction in the comments, like in this case. (Maybe the author should be more specific and put it in the error message, yes)

Open `vi /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py` and search for `check_compatibility(`.

```
def check_compatibility(urllib3_version, chardet_version):
    urllib3_version = urllib3_version.split('.')
    assert urllib3_version != ['dev']  # Verify urllib3 isn't installed from git.

    # Sometimes, urllib3 only reports its version as 16.1.
    if len(urllib3_version) == 2:
        urllib3_version.append('0')

    # Check urllib3 for compatibility.
    major, minor, patch = urllib3_version  # noqa: F811
    major, minor, patch = int(major), int(minor), int(patch)
    # urllib3 >= 1.21.1, <= 1.24     <------------------ here
    assert major == 1
    assert minor >= 21
    assert minor <= 24

    # Check chardet for compatibility.
    major, minor, patch = chardet_version.split('.')[:3]
    major, minor, patch = int(major), int(minor), int(patch)
    # chardet >= 3.0.2, < 3.1.0     <------------------ and here
    assert major == 3
    assert minor < 1
    assert patch >= 2
```

Then, you know the range of versions of `urllib3` and `chardet` compatible. So, you try with:

```
pip uninstall urllib3
pip install urllib3==1.24
pip uninstall chardet
pip install chardet==3.0.9 # this will fail, prompting the correct versions available, so you will try to install 3.0.4 instead
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem with this command

```
pip install --upgrade requests==2.20.1
```

If you see version incompatible message like following, you should try other versions. All versions are: [here](https://pypi.org/project/requests/#history)

```
ERROR: docker-compose 1.24.1 has requirement requests!=2.11.0,!=2.12.2,!=2.18.0,<2.21,>=2.6.1, but you'll have requests 2.21.0 which is incompatible.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an older version of `requests`.

Changing `requests` version from `2.19.1` to `2.20.1` solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try these two commands, hope you will get success.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user urllib3==1.24.3

sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue.

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```

I ran this command and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem with

```
pip install --upgrade requests==2.20.1
```

If you see version incompatible message like following, you should try other versions. All versions are: [here](https://pypi.org/project/requests/#history)

```
ERROR: docker-compose 1.24.1 has requirement requests!=2.11.0,!=2.12.2,!=2.18.0,<2.21,>=2.6.1, but you'll have requests 2.21.0 which is incompatible.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to downgrade urllib3 1.25.2 to 1.24.3, but latter was not found.

```
$ sudo pip install -I urllb3==1.24.3
ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllb3==1.24.3
```

A quick fix that worked for me:
Edit `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py`

In the block:

```
# Check urllib3 for compatibility.
major, minor, patch = urllib3_version  # noqa: F811
major, minor, patch = int(major), int(minor), int(patch)
# urllib3 >= 1.21.1, <= 1.24     
assert major == 1
assert minor >= 21
assert minor <= 24
```

Changed the `assert minor <= 24`  to `assert minor <= 25` and this solved my issue - for now.

There's a bug report on Github https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink/issues/2448

Answer (score 0):

just update pip: sudo pip install -U pip

Answer (score 0):

I got this error running a virtual python environment (Home Assistant) and the above suggestions didn't work for me since the user (homeassistant) didn't have a password or sudo rights.

The solution in this scenario was to simply deactivate the venv environment and then delete the virtual environment directory and recreate the virtual folder.

To deactivate the python3 venv, simple execute the 'deactivate' bash command anywhere inside your virtual environment tree.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue with below urllib3 and chardet versions.

OS      : Ubuntu 18.04

urllib3 : 1.25.6

chardet : 3.0.4

Error : /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/**init**.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.6) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)

solution : update 'requests' pacakge.

$ pip3 install requests

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with miniconda once I have updated the os to Sonoma. Nothing worked but uninstalling and reinstalling it.