# RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.2) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version! Fix

Tags: python, pip, importerror, archlinux

Whenever I run my code with requests or do a pip install I get this message

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.2) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
```

I have tried upgrading chardet, urllib3 and requests but nothing is working, anyone know how can I fix this?

Edit: [RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.9.1) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202238/requestsdependencywarning-urllib3-1-9-1-or-chardet-2-3-0-doesnt-match-a-su) <-- This did not fix my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.9.1) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202238/requestsdependencywarning-urllib3-1-9-1-or-chardet-2-3-0-doesnt-match-a-su)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+RequestsDependencyWarning%3A+urllib3+or+chardet+doesn%27t+match+a+supported+version

Comment: "(link to seeming duplicate) This did not fix my problem." -- can you provide more details as to why it's not a dupe? Did you try all 21 answers from that thread? If so, please describe how they didn't work specifically (what error/result/behavior did you experience). Absent any follow-up, I vote to close this as a dupe. Thanks.

Answer (score 287):

The proper command for fixing this is:

`pip3 install --upgrade requests`

I upgraded from `2.21.0` to `2.24.0` and the error went away.

Answer (score 64):

Simply you have to install latest version of requests

```
  pip3 install requests
```

Comment: "_you have to upgrade you requests_". But this command does not upgrade the request module.

Comment: ^ nor does upgrading even do anything, jfc

Comment: This does not work if the module was already installed.

Answer (score 22):

I fixed this problem with

```
pip install --upgrade requests==2.20.1
```

If you see version incompatible message like following, you should try other versions. All versions are: [here](https://pypi.org/project/requests/#history)

```
ERROR: docker-compose 1.24.1 has requirement requests!=2.11.0,!=2.12.2,!=2.18.0,<2.21,>=2.6.1, but you'll have requests 2.21.0 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: No need to specify versions unless you need to.

Comment: Use either `--upgrade` either `==2.20.1`; it does not make sense to use both at the same time.

Comment: this worked for me , the more advanced version 2-27.1 was apparently incompatible

Answer (score 5):

I got this problem when I tried to run docker-compose:
urllib3 (1.24.1) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version

In my case I solved by remove the docker-compose:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker-compose
```

and installing:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Edit:
Now it should contain `v` on specifying its version.

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.20.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Then run:

`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

Answer (score 4):

Find this and look in **requests/**init**.py** source file:

```
def check_compatibility(urllib3_version, chardet_version):
    urllib3_version = urllib3_version.split('.')
    assert urllib3_version != ['dev']  # Verify urllib3 isn't installed from git.

    # Sometimes, urllib3 only reports its version as 16.1.
    if len(urllib3_version) == 2:
        urllib3_version.append('0')

        # Check urllib3 for compatibility.
        major, minor, patch = urllib3_version  # noqa: F811
        major, minor, patch = int(major), int(minor), int(patch)
        # urllib3 >= 1.21.1, <= 1.24    !HERE!
        assert major == 1
        assert minor >= 21
        assert minor <= 24

        # Check chardet for compatibility.
        major, minor, patch = chardet_version.split('.')[:3]
        major, minor, patch = int(major), int(minor), int(patch)
        # chardet >= 3.0.2, < 3.1.0    !HERE!
        assert major == 3
        assert minor < 1
        assert patch >= 2
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case upgrading requests didn't work. 
`pip3 install requests`

I used [ehh's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56903297/10251345) of downloading docker-compose again

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Then adding execution capability to the file by
`sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and fixed this problem with the command

pip install --upgrade requests==2.20.1

Comment: It's a copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58250787/2745495) from 2019.

Comment: Please don't repeat existing answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34400111)