# AWS lambda: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.6) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version

Tags: aws-lambda, python-requests

I have an AWS lambda program that is getting this warning in logs:

> /var/task/requests/**init**.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.6) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!

I have tried fixes mentioned in other threads such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56155627/requestsdependencywarning-urllib3-1-25-2-or-chardet-3-0-4-doesnt-match-a-s) but have not been able to resolve this

The odd thing is that in my virtualenv, I have:

```
chardet==4.0.0
urllib3==1.25.10
```

... but the warning is complaining about chardet 3.0.4 and urllib 1.26.6. Wondering if this could have something to do with packages being provided by the AWS Lambda environment. I assume that my packages override the defaults they have.

Answer (score 1):

it may be because of an outdated "requests"

try to upgrade request with `pip3 install --upgrade requests`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`pip install -U urllib3 requests`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.